# Sizing photos with new sites

Tags: google-sites

I migrated to new sites and all the image sizes have been altered, I had them to fill the width of the page.  I now have to go through hundreds of photos to alter them.
I see the only way is moving the blue dots but can't see how I maintain the vertical and horizontal size ratio. The old system  with small medium large and 100% was much easier this new sites is hopeless.  It it creating all sorts of problems.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Do you mean new Google Sites? What is the question?

Comment: I just read your previous question, so it looks that you mean Google Sites :)

Comment: Yes I am referring to the migration from Google Classic Sites to New Sites